# how to view the whole list in value_counts() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, data-science

```
df['Amt'].value_counts(sort=True)

45000       3733
67500       3450
22500       3127
18000       2761
27000       2748
            ... 
114332.4       1
27709.65       1
84565.8        1
53137.35       1
25226.1        1
Name:Amt, Length: 4176, dtype: int64
```

How to view the who value counts instead of only few (i.e without have (...) showing the whole count)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
df['Amt'].value_counts(sort=True)
```

Comment: Note: setting max_rows to `None` means that it will display an unlimited number of rows.  See, [Pandas Options and Settings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html)